# Regular expression Range with decimal 0.1 - 7.0

Tags: regex, range

I need a regular expression that should validate decimal point as well as range. Totally 3 number should be present including dot and the value must be greater than 0.0. That means the valid range is from 0.1 to 7.0.

I used the following regex: `^\\d{1,1}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$`

It works fine except for the range validation. What do I need to change?

Comment: I would recommend not using a regular expression for this task, if at all possible. (E.g. use it only as the first stage if at all.)

Comment: Your current regex also allows integers (`5`) and decimals with higher precision (`0.11`) that shouldn't be allowed according to your question text. What do you *really* want?

Comment: `if(s.matches("^\\d{1,1}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$") && Double.valueOf(s) >= 0.1 && Double.valueOf(s) <= 7.0) { ... }`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Regexes are notoriously bad at validating number ranges. But it's possible. You have to break down the number range into the expected *textual* representations of those numbers:

```
^                  # Start of string
(?:                # Either match...
 7(?:\.0)?         # 7.0 (or 7)
|                  # or
 [1-6](?:\.[0-9])? # 1.0-6.9 (or 1-6)
|                  # or
 0?\.[1-9]         # 0.1-0.9 (or .1-.9)
)                  # End of alternation
$                  # End of string
```

As a one-liner:

```
^(?:7(?:\.0)?|[1-6](?:\.[0-9])?|0?\.[1-9])$
```

In Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?:7(?:\\.0)?|[1-6](?:\\.[0-9])?|0?\\.[1-9])$");
```

Comment: In your one liner there is a `|` missing between the second and the third alternative.

Comment: @stema: Oops, guess I pressed `Del` once too often when removing the newlines from the verbose version :). Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @TimPietzcker It not working well. am using this regexp in my java program. it give error "java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: I check this reg in http://regex.powertoy.org/. if i check 0.1 means it not matching. i need to validate decimal and the range is 0.1 to 7.0. B/w this range should not give err msg else should give error msg. plz update me as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: @siva: In a Java String, you need to double the backslashes. When asking regex question, always include the language you're using because of subtle caveats like these. See the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Comment: @TimPietzcker Hi, thanks you so much.. it workin fine. thanks to make me feel happy :)

Comment: @Timpietzcker In this regex one problem. it allow decimal alone. if user enter 4 instead of 4.0. it should not give error message. But, now i face that problem. so, we want to allow user also enter 1,2,3.. 7 whole number also. please can you help me.

Comment: @siva: That's why I asked whether integer values should also be allowed. I've edited the regex. Basically, to match a part optional, just enclose it in `(?:...)?`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Sorry to disturb dude. one more condition is regex should allow if user enter like .1, .2, .3,... and also allow 0.1, 0.2...(It work well in existing code). Both condition should satisfy... Please guide me to work well.. thanks in advance.

Comment: @siva: Easy, just needs one more `?` to make the zero optional. I guess you might want to read a [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info) to get acquainted with some of the most basic regex concepts :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker yeah,I am newbie to regex. sure i ll go through the regex tutorial. thanks

Comment: what if in the above regex i want to include 2 places of decimal, i.e, to accept from 0.00 to 7.00?

Answer (score 0):

To complete the great @TimPietzcker answer,

this Regex...

```
^(?:7(?:\.0)?|[1-6](?:\.(?:[0-9])?)?|0?(?:\.(?:[1-9])?)?)$
```

also match:

```
0
0.
2. 
.2
```

for anyone who needs it !