# Only allow numbers 0-168 including decimals up to two places

Tags: javascript, regex

This is what I have so far:

```
/^(1[0-6][0-8]|1[0-5][0-9]|1[01][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])$/
```

This regex only allows the numbers `0-168` but does not allow any decimal places i.e. `1.5` or `12.56` or `167.99`.

Comment: what do you want to achieve and why don't you work with Number instead?

Comment: Wildly close to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800120/regular-expression-range-with-decimal-0-1-7-0

Comment: Why a regex? `if (var >=0 and var <= 167.99)`

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:\d\d?|1[0-5]\d|16[0-7])(?:\.\d\d?)?$
```

This matches numbers from `0` to `168`, excluding `168` itself.

If you want to add it, just

```
|^168(?:\.00?)?$
```