# How to put regex expression to validate number between 1.0 to 4.5 (range between decimal values)?

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript, validation

I need an expression to validate numbers between 1.0 to 4.5 but it's not working precisely for it.

Expression I'm using: /^[1-4]{0,1}(?:[.]\d{1,2})?$/

Requirement is to only accept value between 1.0 to 4.5

but

```
buildInserForm(): void {
    this.insertLeavesForm = this.fb.group({
     **your text**
      hours: [
        { value: 4.5, disabled: true },
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern(**/^[1-4]{0,1}(?:[.]\d{1,2})?$/**),
        ],
      ],
    });
  }
```

Currently restricting the numbers from 1.0 to 4.0,    But the issue comes in decimal points, it shows an error if entered any number between 6-9 in decimal places, like 1.7,2.8, 3.9.

acceptance criteria are 1.0  to 4.5.

[image: Picture of showing where value is being entered wrong]

This image shows that value is getting entered to multiple decimal places which is wrong,
Only single decimal place value is required.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to get the number using a simpler regex, convert to float and then do a simple comparison. I think that would also be faster.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a regex that I created.
**pattern(/^[1-3]{0,1}(?:[.][0-9]{0,1})?[4]{0,1}(?:[.][0-5]{0,1})?$/)**

*Explaination*

```
/^[1-3]{0,1}(?:[.][0-9]{0,1})?[4]{0,1}(?:[.][0-5]{0,1})?$/


/^            start of the input
[1-3]         First input to be taken between
{0,1}         This shows how many times it can be repeated
(             Parenthesis shows next entered digit is optional
?             Question mark is for using digit zero or once
:[.]          This is for what the next Character would be eg ".", "@"
[0-9]         input to be taken between.
{0,1}         This shows how many times it can be repeated.
)             Option part closes
?             Question mark is for using digit zero or once.
[4]           This shows what can be other input that can be taken
{0,1}         How many times it can be use , SO in this case 0 or 1 times


(?:[.]       There after again same option part  with decimal point

             decimal value of 4and its limitation for 0 to 5
[0-5]        This is to set limitation 0-5 as per our requirement
{0,1}        Its existence 0 or 1 times
)            Close of optional part.
?            Thereafter showing the existence of an optional part once or twice.
$/           Shows to match expression after it.
```

Comment: This one worked exactly correct for one decimal place between 1.0 to 4.5 in which decimal place is optional

Answer (score 2):

Regex are pretty bad to check number ranges. Should it consider non decimal numbers? What if there is more than one decimal point? What if you should ever want to increase/decrease range? Here's more on the topic: [Regular expression Range with decimal 0.1 - 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800120/regular-expression-range-with-decimal-0-1-7-0)

I would suggest simple `min/max` Validators. Plus this would also let you control if user value is below or above criteria, letting you to display custom error messages appropriately, for example. Whereas regex will simply evaluate to true/false.

```js
[
 Validators.required,
 Validators.min(1),
 Validators.max(4.5),
 Validators.maxLength(3)
]
```

Comment: One of the best option , but I wanted to show error if it crosses one decimal place , and it will not show error as 1.22222 is smaller than its max value 4.5.    Thanks for your efforts

Comment: @AmanKumarSingh: You could also simply set 'maxlength' to overcome your last problem.

Comment: @PoulBak simple `maxLenght` validator is not good in general to check decimal numbers. If maxLenght is 3 and input is 10.5? Then the length would be 4. But in this limited case when max value is 4.5 then yes, maxlength of 3 would work.

Comment: Yes, I meant as an extra requirement, still using your code. Together I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```regex
^(?:[1-3](?:\.\d{1,2})?|4(?:\.(?:[0-4][0-9]|50?)?))$
```

### Demo

This regex pattern says to match:

```regex
^                            start of the input
(?:
    [1-3]                    match 1-3
    (?:\.\d{1,2})?           followed by optional decimal and 1 or 2 digits
    |                        OR
    4                        match 4
    (?:
        \.                   decimal point
        (?:[0-4][0-9]|50?)?  match 4.00 to 4.49 or 4.5 or 4.50
    )
)
$                            end of the input
```

Comment: Will let you know after all my parameters, Thanks